# On the change of objective function values between Simplex-Iterations

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

Background (skippable):
I asked this question in a lecture quite some time ago and the lecturer couldn't really answer it. This question bothered me since then, since I couldn't be able to answer it.

---

Given an arbitrary linear program in standard form

$\text{maximize }c^T \cdot x \\
\text{subject to }Ax \leq b, \forall i:x_i \geq 0.$

Let the Simplex-Algorithm be applied to it and let $x^0$ denote objective function value for the first basis.
My question then is:

Does every additional iteration, which means a variable enters and another leaves the basis, yield an improvement on the last? That is, if the Simplex
algorithm didn't terminate yet. So formally, if the algorithm does $n$ iterations, is it always true that $x^{k+1} > x^{k} \ \forall k \in \{0,1,...,n-1\}$?

If so, why does this hold?

If not, does there exist a rule on the choice of the new pivot element that guarantees the objective function value to always increase? If so, what rule guarantees that? If not, why does there not exist such a rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this need not be true. In case of degeneracy, you will change the basis but not improve the objective value. Geometrically this means that you are in a vertex of the polyhedron describing the feasible set and the change of basis does not lead you to a new vertex. Hence, you are stuck in the same vertex for one (or possibly more) iterations and you do not improve the objective value. Degeneracy occurs when there are redundant constraints in the problem.

Comment: That perfectly makes sense. However, that leads to another question. If I am stuck on a vertex the objective function value does not improve, it stays the same, but does there exist some iteration for which this value actually gets worse?

Comment: @Korosensei No, the simplex algorithm will always only pick a direction that does not worsen the objective value. However, you have to choose a pivot rule for choosing the new basic variables which avoids that you get stuck in a non-optimal vertex in an infinite loop. One such pivot rule which makes sure that this does not happen is Bland's rule, for example. But there are also other pivot rules around.

Comment: Thank you very much, that answers my question! But how does one show that this holds? Just a rough idea should be sufficient

Comment: What exactly would you like to show? That Bland's rule avoids getting caught in an infiinte loop or that you only ever move in directions that improve the objective value?

Comment: That you only ever move in directions that improve the objective value.

Comment: For how many iteration will it be stuck on the same iteration can we know that

Comment: @Upstart This depends on how you choose the elements leaving and joining the basis. In the worst case you get stuck in an infinite loop if the pivot rule is bad.